# DOM re-render without any update in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
export default class setState extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            data:[],`enter code here`
            'header':'this is header'
        }
    }

    updateState(){
        var arr = this.state.data;
        var temp = 'setState... ';
        arr.push(temp);

        this.setState({data:arr});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Set State</h1>
                <button onClick={this.updateState.bind(this)} >Update State </button>
                <p>{this.state.data}</p>
                <h3>{this.state.header}</h3>
                <h2>Random value : {Math.random()}</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't want to update h2 tag the "Random Value". When i click on the "Update button" i am pushing value in the array and doing "setState". But it also update my h2 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `Math.random` function in your render function will cause the value been changed on each render, instead, you can initialise your random value in constructor.

```
export default class setState extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            data:[],
            'header':'this is header'
        }
        //init random value here
        this.randomValue = Math.random();
    }

    updateState(){
        var arr = this.state.data;
        var temp = 'setState... ';
        arr.push(temp);

        this.setState({data:arr});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Set State</h1>
                <button onClick={this.updateState.bind(this)} >Update State </button>
                <p>{this.state.data}</p>
                <h3>{this.state.header}</h3>
                <h2>Random value : {this.randomValue}</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```